# How to use SQL wildcards in LINQ to Entity Framework

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a query that looks like this:

```
IQueryable<Profile> profiles = from p in connection.Profiles
    where profile.Email.Contains(txtSearch)
    select p;
```

I know that when this is converted to SQL it uses a `LIKE '%<value of txtSearch>%'` but if `txtSearch = "jon%gmail.com"` it converts it to `LIKE '%jon~%gmail.com%'.  The ~ escapes the % in the middle that is a wild card.  How do I get around that?  I need to be able to put wild cards into my LINQ to EF searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible directly with linq because you can call only basic string functions like `Contains`, `StartsWith` or `EndsWith`. [It is possible with Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399359.aspx) so you can combine these approaches.

```
var query = new ObjectQuery<Profile>(
    @"SELECT VALUE p
      FROM CsdlContainerName.Profiles AS p
      WHERE p.Email LIKE '" + wildcardSearch + "'",
    context);

var result = query.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

ESQL injection strikes back :)

Second version without injection vulnerability (I didn't try it but it should work):

```
var commandText =
    @"SELECT VALUE p
      FROM CsdlContainerName.Profiles AS p
      WHERE p.Email LIKE @search";

var query = new ObjectQuery<Profile>(commandText, context);
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("search", wildcardSearch));

var result = query.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: The page I am creating is an admin page so I am not worried about a SQL injection attack but wouldn't the above method open me up to a SQL injection attack?

Comment: I think it does but actually didn't try it (see my comment bellow the code snippet). But you can also use version with parameters - I will add it as second example.