# Entity Framework 4.1 - How to prevent EF escaping wildcards?

Tags: entity-framework, escaping, wildcard

Is there a way to tell EF not to escape my wildcards?

My current solution looks like this:

```
 var movieNameWithProperWildcards = string.Format("%{0}%",    
 movieName.ToLower().Replace("*", "%"));

 var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "searchParameter", Value =   
 movieNameWithProperWildcards };

 List<Movie> movieEntities = MovieContext.Movies.SqlQuery("select * from Movies WHERE 
 Lower(title) like @searchParameter", sqlParameter).ToList();
```

But that would be much nicer:

```
 List<Movie> movieEntities = MovieContext.Movies.Where(movie =>  
 movie.Title.ToLower().Contains(movieName));
```

br
rene_r

Comment: And what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Because one of the advantages of an OR-Mapper is, that I can use LINQ-Queries and don't have to think about writing sql-queries. And its such a common thing so search with wildcards, so why do I have to create such a cumbersome workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `LIKE` so you can use either your way, [ESQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399359.aspx) or Linq-to-entities and `Contains` canonical function. ORM tool is not responsible for translating wildcards from your representation to wildcards representation in the database - you must do it yourselves with tools provided by ORM.

Generally this should work:

```
var query = from m in ctx.Movies
            where m.Name.ToLower().Contains(movieName)
            select m;
```

Both `String.ToLower` and `String.Contains` are in the list of [supported canonical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx).

Comment: Well, Linq-to-Sql provides a like function, that can work with wildcards, nhibernate also provides such a function, so why there is no way with ef(by the way there are a lot of people who struggling with this issue/behavior). Of course Contains is working more or less for simple task, but how would you do such a search just with contains: searchTerm="*matr*I" ? br

Comment: I would use ESQL or expose model defined function from EDMX. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425187/how-to-use-sql-wildcards-in-linq-to-entity-framework/5425764#5425764

Answer (score 0):

Check that the query that gets executed is right. See here how you can use context's Log to do that http://www.thereforesystems.com/view-query-generate-by-linq-to-sql/

Comment: Thx for the info, but its not related to my question.