# SQL LIKE Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, linq, wildcard, sql-like

My question uses the following code -

```
string searchString = dropdownlist.SelectedValue;

List objects = (from o in Object.List()
                       where dropdownlist.SelectedIndex <= 0 || 
                           o.CustomField.Contains(searchString)
                       orderby o.Date descending
                       select order).ToList();
```

The situation I am running into is as follows -  The items in the drop down list are generic messages such as "Customer '{0}' has '{1}' orders".   On the object side, o.CustomField would look something like "Customer 'Bob' has '5' orders".  Obviously, this means that

```
o.CustomField.Contains(searchString)
```

will not return anything.  I've been looking into wildcards but have not been able to achieve a successful return. This is what I was trying for a wildcard set up:

```
searchString = dropdownlist.SelectedValue.Replace("{0}", "*").Replace("{1}", "*");
```

I'm wondering if there is any cleaner way than to sit around and parse out all the different substrings between '{' or '}'.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want to match the string: `Customer '{0}' has '{1}' orders` with: `Customer * has * orders`?

Comment: Correct, that is what I am going for.

Comment: Look into using a regular expression. It is a little investment but it will pay of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve your goal by using regular expressions. See Regex.Match Method.
You can transform your selected string from the dropdown list into a regular expression then use the Match method in your LINQ query.

```
Regex r = new Regex(String.Format ("Customer {0} has {1} orders", "([^\s]+)",  "([^\s]+)"));
```

This code:

```
o.CustomField.Contains(searchString)
```

can then be changed to:

```
r.Match(o.CustomField).Success
```

Comment: This doesn't work on LINQ

Comment: @Chesare Provide some example code by opening a new question. Come back here and point me to the new question.

Comment: This code causes **error "LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match Match(System.String)'"**:
`Regex r = new Regex("HR\\d{4}");
var q = from eq in db.CataEquiposRenta
            where r.Match(eq.NUMEROINTERNO).Success
            select new
            {
                eq.IDEQUIPO,
                Number = eq.NUMEROINTERNO.Substring(2)
            };`

Comment: This code (**using `SqlFunctions.PatIndex`**) works fine:

`// Formato de numero interno: HR1234

var query = from eq in db.CataEquiposRenta
            where SqlFunctions.PatIndex("HR[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%", eq.NUMEROINTERNO) == 1
            orderby eq.NUMEROINTERNO descending
            select new
            {
                eq.IDEQUIPO,
                Number = eq.NUMEROINTERNO.TrimEnd().Substring(2)
            };`

Answer (score 0):

Just do a [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) on `{\d+}`, replacing it with `*`.

Something like:

```
string s = Regex.Replace(input, @"{\d+}", "*");
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing a bit more investigation into Regex since it was mentioned in the above comment and I think this will work best for what I'm hoping to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425187/how-to-use-sql-wildcards-in-linq-to-entity-framework)
Or use combination of `field.StartsWith("Customers") && field.EndsWith("orders") && field.Contains("has")`